# Angular 6 - Update works but error with most imports - 'Cannot find module...'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I've upgraded to Angular 6, including the latest version of Angular Material and RxJS, but a lot of my @angular imports are showing the '*Cannot find module*...' error in VSCode, despite the modules being present in my node_modules folder.

No issues running the app itself, everything works fine since updating rxjs and changing some of the attribute directives for angular material, but I have a lot of warnings appearing in each file.

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "angular-5-firebase",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "main.js",
  "build": {
    "appId": "NickWCook.Angular5FirebaseFinanceManager",
    "productName": "Angular 5 Firebase Finance Manager"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test --browser ChromeHeadless",
    "watch": "ng test --browser ChromeHeadless",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "ng build --prod && firebase deploy",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.15",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.3.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.6.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^5.0.4",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jasmine": "^3.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.21.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngx-electron": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/nickwcook/firebase-work.git",
  "author": "Nick Cook <nick@nickwcook.com>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds likely the VS studio is still using `.angular-cli.json` instead of `.angular.json` You may have to wait for an update. I had a similar issue using Webclipse

Comment: The cli file was replaced by angular.json during the update

Comment: Yeah i'm not sure that VS studio knows to use angular.json instead

Comment: Surely the application would not run correctly then if I'm using the internal terminal?

Comment: i think the internal terminal is just a link to your cmd or runs on top of it. Have you tried copying the the old .angular-cli.json back in and see if that removes the editor errors?

Comment: I'll give that a go, but I still don't see how this will help in solving the issue given angular 6 must use the angular.json file

Comment: it'll determine editor or angular error. Also a fresh app might render a different result. I pretty much spent a whole day with this problem to revert back to ng5 :/